# summation of alternating function in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

If the input is 4 the output should be 2--->
f(4) =  - 1  + 2  - 3  + 4  = 2

but the code doesn't give any output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; cin>>n;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
        if (i%2 != 0){
            i = -i;
        }
        sum += i;
    }
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you used the wrong tag (`css`).

Comment: Unfortunately, you will discover that the coding puzzle site where this coding puzzle is likely from will still fail this, because of "time limit exceeded" for values of several million. This is because the coding puzzle site is a scam, taking advantage of people who want to learn C++ by promising that all they need to do is solve their silly coding puzzles. This coding puzzle is really a simple mathematical formula, that does not require adding numbers, like that, but just a single, simple, formula. Someone who wants to learn C++ is not going to learn anything by knowing what the formula is.

Comment: Hint: you should not modify the loop index `i` inside the loop.

Comment: Track the value of `i` in your loop, you will see that `i <= n` is always true, so your loop never finishes and you see no output

Comment: you should not write a loop to solve this in the first place. Do the maths first: `-1 + 2 -3 + 4 == (-1+2) + (-3+4) == 1 + 1 == 4/2`. you only need to check if `n` is odd or even. The rest is trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need an `endl` when printing so that the output buffer gets flushed to the console.

```
cout << sum << endl;
```

e:
In the for loop, you set `i = -i`. This makes it so that `i` will never be able to reach `n`.

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0)
        sum += i;
    else
        sum -= i;
}
```

Comment: didn't work also

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does nothing get printed? Does the code finish executing?

Comment: Ok so I just ran it, and the program doesn't finish. This means that there's a problem  in the for loop. I'll edit this to show the actual solution.

Comment: nothing gets printed as before

Comment: @john yes I understood you but how can I solve the problem

Comment: Don't modify `i` in the loop, this answer now shows one way.

Answer (score 1):

We already know the problem:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
   if (i%2 != 0){
       i = -i;      // <-- Bad Idea.
                    // Can you imagine what the sequence of 'i' looks like?
                    // It just keeps alternating between 1, -1 and 0.
   }
   sum += i;
}
```

There's a possible approach that's only variable away from this snippet. I'll wrap it into a function, so that it can be more easily tested.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace b {
  constexpr int alternating_sum(int n)
  {
    int sum{};
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
      int value = i;     // <-- Let's use this, instead of messing with i.
      if ( i % 2 != 0)
      {
        value = -value;  
      }
      sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

int main()
{
  // Let's test it:
  using namespace b;
  static_assert(alternating_sum(1) == -1);
  static_assert(alternating_sum(2) == -1 + 2);
  static_assert(alternating_sum(3) == -1 + 2 - 3);
  static_assert(alternating_sum(4) == -1 + 2 - 3 + 4);
  
  std::cout << "So far, so good...\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I also wrapped it into a `namespace`, while avoiding `using namespace std`<sup>1</sup>, because I'd like to play a little more.

Maybe it helps to see how the sequence "grows", so we can add this snippet to the `main` function:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << alternating_sum(i) << '\n';
}
```

It outputs the following

```
-1
1
-2
2
-3
3
-4
4
-5
5
```

That seems like a pattern. One we can reproduce without a loop, with just a little math:

```
namespace c
{
  constexpr int alternating_sum(int n)
  {
    if ( n % 2 != 0 )
    {
      return -(n + 1) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
      return n / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

To test it, we just have to change `using namespace b;` into `using namespace c;` in `main`.

---

<sup>1)  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)</sup>

Comment: You can simplify even more by have a "sign" variable that toggles between -1 and 1.  Example:  `sum += (sign_variable) * (term);` and then do `sign_variable *= -1;`.  Try it!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah. That would also be the "correct" way of writing "monstrosity" like `pow(-1, i) * i`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the `i = -i`, thus the for loop should be changed to something like:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        sum += i;
    } else {
        sum -= i;
    }
}
```